# How effectively start python-Django developement?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I know python, But I am new to python-development, I want to learn python-Django. I have read the Django in Tutorials point also. Currently, I am trying to understand the logic from this link (https://github.com/mrsarm/django-coleman). Please suggest me where I have to start to learn python-Django more effectively?. Should I learn it from scratch or learn it from any Django book or any useful websites?.

Answer (score 1):

Start by that, I have start with that too: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/intro/

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

First start by [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) .

Then you can use :

1 . http://slash4.de/blog/learn-django-in-4-hours

2 . https://djangobook.com/